# CLNDR - how to pass event info to a separate DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, calendar

I am currently putting together a page that would use the CLNDR plugin (http://kylestetz.github.io/CLNDR/), a jQuery plugin ('clndr.js') for creating custom calendars.

1. The page is a .html page which is then inserted by javascript into a .php file. I have to use .php as our server does not run php codes in .html files.
2. The 'clndr.js' uses 'moments.js', 'underscore.js' and a file 'site.js' provided by kylestetz together with the plugin. This 'site.js' contains the event information (dates with events to be used in the calendar generated by the 'clndr.js') in an array like this:

   ```
   var eventArray = [
   { date: '2015.07.25', title: 'Artpolis Kick-off', location: ' ott. 2.', url: 'esemeny/esemeny_reszletes_150535_01.html', type: 'holiday' },
   { date: '2015.06.25', title: 'Smartpolis Kick-off', location: ' SZTNH, Bp., Garibaldi u. 2.', url: 'esemeny/esemeny_reszletes_150535_01.html'},
   { date: '2015.05.26', title: 'ŰR-LÉPTÉK ', location: 'BME K ép. díszterem ', url: 'esemeny/ ' },
   { date: '2015.05.21', title: 'Smart City tagozat', location: ' BME V1 ép. Neumann tárgyaló.', url: 'esemeny/ '  },
   { date: '2015.02.13', title: 'H-SPACE 2015 ', location: ' BME I ép. előadó.', url: 'esemeny/ '  }];
   ```
3. This 'site.js' file also defines where to put the calendar:

(sorry, sometimes I can make code formatting work, sometimes not)

```
calendars.clndr2 = $('.cal2').clndr({
template: $('#template-calendar').html(),
events: eventArray,
```

4. This is the javascript I use in the HEAD part of the .php file to insert the .html file containing the calendar:

(sorry, sometimes I can make code formatting work, sometimes not)

```
<script> 
$(function(){
  $("#includedContentCalendar").load("../test-clndr-example.html"); 
});
```

and in the BODY part:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
<h2>Calendar</h2>
<div id="includedContentCalendar"></div>
</div>
```

5. CLNDR has a click event in the 'site.js' file that can be used to pass the event information stored in the array to the browser console:

   ```
   clickEvents: {
   click: function(target) {
   console.log(target);
   }
   },
   ```
6. Now, I would like this clickevents to display the event information on the .html page, in a separate  `<div id="event information">`. Here the event information would be shown when a date is clicked that has an event attached to it in the array.

I did not find a description to do this in the "manual", and I was directed to this forum from github.

Can you please advise how to pass the event information stored in 'site.js' to a specific DIV ID in the .html file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `click` handler is given a variable `target` which contains an array of `events` (it is possible to have more than one event).

Here is an example on how you would to get the title of the first event and set it to a div:

```
click: function(target) {
    var info = target.events[0].title;
    $("#event-information").text(info);
}
```

Note: you can't have spaces in your `id`, so we used `<div id="event-information">` instead.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/alan0xd7/yfL9njce/

**Update:**

Here is an example on how to work with `url` and making links:

```
click: function(target) {

    var title = target.events[0].title;
    var url = target.events[0].url;

    var link = $("<a>"); // create a link tag
    link.text(title); // set the title
    link.attr("href", url); // set the url

    $("#event-information").html(link);

}
```

Note that we used `.html()` this time, as we are now inserting HTML code (as opposed of just text like last time).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/alan0xd7/yfL9njce/3/

Comment: Thanks, this works. An additional question: how can I pass the url information from the eventArray together with the title?

Comment: `target.events[0]` will basically have the same properties as the event you set in your `eventArray`, which means it will have `date`, `title`, `location`, `url` and `type`.

Comment: So if you want `url`, you can just get it from `target.events[0].url`

Comment: with `target.events[0]` I got "[object Object]". I would like the Title be clickable with the URL data. Please note that I am a _beginner_ novice :-) in this...

Comment: I've updated my answer and added another example, please take a look.

Comment: Off topic: if you are interested in web programming (HTML/CSS/JS), I highly recommend you do some online courses at [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn). It is free and very popular.

Comment: Thank you for the update and the recommendation. I am currently reading a course but the material is not yet at this point. Thanks again.